# SecurityNegotiationException - Retrieving token from web service

Tags: c#, web-services, adfs, wif

I'm attempting to move from WIF 3.5 and onto WIF 4.5. However, the conversion is proving to be more difficult than I anticipated. The questions will correspond to the comments in the code.

Full error message:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Authentication Failed --->
>
> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Secure
> channel cannot be opened because security negotiation with the remote
> endpoint has failed.  This may be due to absent or incorrectly
> specified EndpointIdentity in the EndpointAddress used to create the
> channel.  Please verify the EndpointIdentity specified or implied by
> the EndpointAddress correctly identifies the remote endpoint.
>
> Secure channel cannot be opened because security negotiation with the
> remote endpoint has failed.  This may be due to absent or incorrectly
> specified EndpointIdentity in the EndpointAddress used to create the
> channel.  Please verify the EndpointIdentity specified or implied by
> the EndpointAddress correctly identifies the remote endpoint.

#1. Which username/password combination is needed and which is not?

#2. This is where SecurityNegotiationException is thrown. What am I missing exactly?

So, am I way off or is it something simple I'm missing? Do I need to entirely rewrite how the `WSTrustChannelFactory` is being created?

Code:

```
public string GetToken(string url, string domain, string realm, string username, string password)
{
    string rp = realm;
    string token = "";

    WSTrustChannelFactory trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory
    (
        new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
        new EndpointAddress(new Uri(url))
    );
        
    trustChannelFactory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
    trustChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = domain;
    trustChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = username; // #1; not sure which pair is needed?
    trustChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = password;

    trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
    trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    try
    {
        RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken(RequestTypes.Issue, KeyTypes.Bearer);
        rst.AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(rp);
        rst.TokenType = SecurityTokenTypes.Saml;

        WSTrustChannel channel = (WSTrustChannel)trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        GenericXmlSecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst) as GenericXmlSecurityToken; // #2; Exception thrown here
        token = token.TokenXml.OuterXml;
    }
    catch (SecurityNegotiationException e)
    {
        LogError("Authentication Failed", e);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        LogError("Unable to authenticate", e);
    }
    catch (CommunicationException e)
    {
        LogError("Communication exception", e);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogError("Unknown exception", e);
    }
    return token;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to continue to use WIF 3.5 for now and will have an entire rewrite for WIF 4.5 instead of trying to do something that isn't possible.

There was simply too much change and not enough documentation to "shoehorn" our existing code from WIF 3.4 to WIF 4.5

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a **SecurityTokenHandlerCollection**

```
        public SecurityToken GetToken(string url, string realm, string username, string password)
        {
            string rp = realm;
        
            WS2007HttpBinding binding = new WS2007HttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential, false);

            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
            binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;

            EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url);

            WSTrustChannelFactory factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, endpoint);
            factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;

            WSTrustChannel channel = (WSTrustChannel) factory.CreateChannel();

            RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken
            {
                RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
                KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,
                AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(rp),              
                TokenType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0"
            };

            GenericXmlSecurityToken genericXmlSecurityToken = (GenericXmlSecurityToken) channel.Issue(rst, out RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr);          

            SecurityTokenHandlerCollection tokenHandlers = new SecurityTokenHandlerCollection(
                new SecurityTokenHandler[]
                {
                    new SamlSecurityTokenHandler(), 
                    new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler()
                }
            );
            tokenHandlers.Configuration.AudienceRestriction = new AudienceRestriction();
            tokenHandlers.Configuration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri(rp));

            TrustedIssuerNameRegistry trustedIssuerNameRegistry = new TrustedIssuerNameRegistry();
            tokenHandlers.Configuration.IssuerNameRegistry = trustedIssuerNameRegistry;

            SecurityToken token =
                tokenHandlers.ReadToken(
                    new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(genericXmlSecurityToken.TokenXml.OuterXml)));

            return token;
        }

        public class TrustedIssuerNameRegistry : IssuerNameRegistry
        {
            public override string GetIssuerName(SecurityToken securityToken)
            {
                return "Trusted Issuer";
            }
        }
```